How to get the full response stream from /v1/threads/{threadid}/runs in js
While Builing a Chrome extension with OpenAi assistant API, i came across a method that returns a streamed response, but my code is just getting the first node of the response all the time, and the one i want is almost at the end with a "event":"thread.message.completed" tag and a Content parameter
background.js
"use strict";

// On Chrome Install
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ 'apiKey': 'sk-proj-XXX' }, () => {
        console.log("API key has been stored.");
    });
});

// Listen for the browser action click event to open the form in a new window
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html"),
        type: "popup",
        width: 400,
        height: 800
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.action === "fetchAnswer") {
        chrome.storage.local.get('apiKey', async (result) => {
            if (result.apiKey) {
                try {
                    const threadResponse = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/threads', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result.apiKey,
                            'OpenAI-Beta': 'assistants=v2'
                        },
                    });

                    if (!threadResponse.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Network response threads was not ok ' + threadResponse.statusText);
                    }

                    const threadData = await threadResponse.json();
                    const threadId = threadData.id;

                    const messageResponse = await fetch(`https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/${threadId}/messages`, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result.apiKey,
                            'OpenAI-Beta': 'assistants=v2'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            role: "user",
                            content: [
                                {
                                    type: "text",
                                    text: message.question
                                }
                            ]
                        })
                    });

                    if (!messageResponse.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Network response messages was not ok ' + messageResponse.statusText);
                    }

                    const runResponse = await fetch(`https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/${threadId}/runs`, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result.apiKey,
                            'OpenAI-Beta': 'assistants=v2'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            assistant_id: "asst_xxx"
                        })
                    });

                    if (!runResponse.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Network response runs was not ok ' + runResponse.statusText);
                    }

                    const reader = runResponse.body.getReader();
                    const stream = new ReadableStream({
                        start(controller) {
                        function push() {
                            reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
                            if (done) {
                                controller.close();
                                return;
                            }
                            controller.enqueue(value);
                            push();
                            });
                        }
                        push();
                        }
                    });

                    const response = new Response(stream, {
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                    });
                    const readerStream = response.body.getReader();
                    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
                    let buffer = '';
                    let resultStream = '';

                    while (true) {
                        const { done, value } = await readerStream.read();
                        if (done) break;

                        buffer += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
                        let boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n\n');

                        while (boundary !== -1) {
                            const eventString = buffer.slice(0, boundary);
                            buffer = buffer.slice(boundary + 2);
                            if (eventString.trim()) {
                                const event = JSON.parse(eventString.trim());
                                handleEvent(event);
                            }
                            boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n\n');
                        }
                        console.log("Boundary: " + boundary + '\n');
                        console.log("buffer: " + buffer + '\n');
                        resultStream += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
                        console.log(resultStream + '\n');
                    }

                    sendResponse({ text: resultStream });
/*
                    const readerStream = response.body.getReader();
                    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
                    let buffer = '';

                    while (true) {
                        const { done, value } = await readerStream.read();
                        if (done) break;

                        buffer += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
                        let boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n\n');

                        while (boundary !== -1) {
                        const eventString = buffer.slice(0, boundary);
                        buffer = buffer.slice(boundary + 2);
                        if (eventString.trim()) {
                            const event = JSON.parse(eventString.trim());
                            handleEvent(event);
                        }
                        boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n\n');
                        }
                    }
                    sendResponse({ status: 'completed' });
                    
                    */
                } catch (error) {
                    sendResponse({ error: error.message });
                }
            } else {
                sendResponse({ error: 'API key not found.' });
            }
        });

        return true; // Will respond asynchronously.
    }
});

function handleEvent(event) {
    switch (event.event) {
      case 'thread.message.delta':
        console.log('Text Delta:', event.data);
        break;
      case 'thread.message.completed':
        console.log('Message Completed:', event.data);
        const textContent = event.data.content.find(c => c.type === 'text').text.value;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'displayText', text: textContent });
        break;
      case 'thread.run.step.completed':
        console.log('Step Completed:', event.data);
        break;
      case 'thread.run.completed':
        console.log('Run Completed:', event.data);
        break;
      default:
        console.log('Unknown event:', event);
    }
  }

manifest.json
{
  "name": "Ensight Plus Helper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "Ask questions about the user guide",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://api.openai.com/*"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "EnSightLogo.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "EnSightLogo.png"
  }
}

popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="module" src="./popup.js"></script>
    <title>EnsightPlus Guide</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f9;
            color: #333;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 400px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 2rem;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
        }
        #chatbox {
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            overflow-y: scroll;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        .message {
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
        }
        .message.user {
            text-align: right;
            color: #4a90e2;
        }
        .message.bot {
            text-align: left;
            color: #333;
        }
        textarea {
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 600px;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            resize: none;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        button {
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #ea580b;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }
        button:hover {
            background-color: #ef7c3b;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>What do you need help with today?</h1>
    <div id="chatbox"></div>
    <textarea id="question" name="ensightgpt" placeholder="Enter your message here."></textarea>
    <button id="askButton">Send</button>
</body>
</html>

popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const askButton = document.getElementById('askButton');
    const questionInput = document.getElementById('question');
    const chatbox = document.getElementById('chatbox');

    askButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const question = questionInput.value;
        if (question.trim() === "") return;

        addMessageToChatbox(question, 'user');
        questionInput.value = '';

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "fetchAnswer", question: question }, (response) => {
            if (response.error) {
                addMessageToChatbox('Error: ' + response.error, 'bot');
            } else {
                addMessageToChatbox(response.text, 'bot');
            }
        });
    });

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (request.action === 'displayText') {
            addMessageToChatbox(request.text, 'bot');
        }
    });

    function addMessageToChatbox(message, sender) {
        const messageDiv = document.createElement('div');
        messageDiv.classList.add('message', sender);
        messageDiv.textContent = message;
        chatbox.appendChild(messageDiv);
        chatbox.scrollTop = chatbox.scrollHeight;
    }
});


Does it take more than 30 seconds for the response to arrive? If so, the background script simply dies during fetch() due to a bug in ManifestV3. You actually don't need the background script or messaging for this task, just move the network fetching code to the popup.
